# Can I Close Kivy Window and Open It Again?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there a way to launch kivy twice from the same process, while closing kivy's window when not needed?  MWE:

```
from kivy.app import App
app = App ()
app.run ()
app.root_window.close ()
App().run () # ERROR: "no event listeners have been created" and "Application will leave"
```

I want the second `App().run()` to create another window, without having to re-launch Python.  Is this possible?

What I'm trying to do is that I'm trying to debug a kivy program from the Python repl.  I open the `App`, interact with it, find a bug, dismiss the window by clicking its "X" button, and then I go on to test (from the same repl) the non-GUI parts of the program that caused the bug.  But the window sticks around all this time, which is a major nuisance as I use a tabbing window manager.  I want to be able to close this window while I'm working on the non-GUI parts of the program, and then come back to launch the GUI again, without having to exit and restart the repl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on the web. Add a method:

```
def reset():
    import kivy.core.window as window
    from kivy.base import EventLoop
    if not EventLoop.event_listeners:
        from kivy.cache import Cache
        window.Window = window.core_select_lib('window', window.window_impl, True)
        for cat in Cache._categories:
            Cache._objects[cat] = {}
```

Then you can restart the app like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
app = App ()
app.run ()
app.root_window.close ()
reset()
App().run ()
```